# Eclipse Mars Java - Error in Preferences - Could not accept changes

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, user-accounts

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Enterprise SP1
**Eclipse Edition**: Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) Java

**How to error is shown**

- Eclipse Menu: *Windows -> Preferences*
- Select from tree on the left *General -> Network Connections*
- This shows the error **Could not accept changes** with the message **The current displayed page contains invalid values.** (See also the screenshot)

[image]

- After a few times selecting different node in the tree, it sometimes is possible to get into *Network Connections*. But it does not appear correctly. The pull down *Active Provider* has no content. Nothing can be edited.

[image]

Who knows the solution?

**REMARK:** This happens within the organisation. It happens for users with a *tester* account, but **NOT** for user with a *developer* account. Sounds like something to do with profiles or so. But no idea what to check / verify etc. Suggestions and tips are welcome.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me starting eclipse with "-clean" resolved it.